# lex default token definition syntax

Tags: lex

I guess this is a simple question, but I have found no reference. I have a small lex file defining some tokens from a string and altering them (actually converting them to uppercase).

Basically it is a list of commands like this:

> word {setToUppercase(yytext);}

Where setToUppercase is a procedure to change case and store it.

I need to have the complete entry string with the altered words. Is there a way to define a default token / rest of tokens so I can asociate them with an unaltered storage in an output string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in one shot with:

`.|\n {save_str(yytext);}`

Answer (score 0):

I said it was an easy one.

```
.   {save_str(yytext);}
\n  {save_str(yytext);}
```

This way all characters and newline are treated.